# WWW::Mechanize with Perl

Tags: perl, web-crawler, www-mechanize

I'm currently new to using WWW::Mechanize and am using it to build a web scraping tool that will go onto a school website and pull course data so that the website I'm building can recognize conflicts.  I currently have this code in Perl:

```
#!/user/bin/perl  
use warnings;
use strict;
use WWW::Mechanize;

my $browser = WWW::Mechanize->new;
$browser->get( 'https://registrar.ucdavis.edu/courses/search/index.cfm');
$browser->form_number(3); #Search Form
$browser->select('subject', 'AAS');
$browser->submit();

print $browser->content();
```

The way the website works, you go in, select a subject area, and then click "Search".  Then a table populates based off what you selected in the forms above.

I'm currently focused on just getting my script to select one option from the dropdown menu, click "Search" and then copy the results, but for one, I'm not sure if it's actually working (It's not giving me any errors, but I'm not sure it's doing anything) and two, I'm not sure how to view the data that pops up in the table.  Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Cross post at perlmonks: http://perlmonks.com/?node_id=1098948

Comment: Haha yeah, you probably ran into my other post when you googled my question.  Thought I might post on another site to see if people using that site had a solution. Not everyone on perlmonks is on stack overflow and vice versa.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Javascript magic is used on this page. You need to **make POST request manually**.

Here is POST request (from Firefox's HTTPFox extension):

```
termYear    2014
term    10
course_number   
multiCourse 
course_title    
instructor  
subject AAS
course_start_eval   -
course_start_time   -
course_end_eval -
course_end_time -
course_status   -
course_level    -
course_units    -
virtual -
termCode    201410
runMe   1
clearMe 1
reorder 
gettingResults  0
search  Search
_cf_nodebug true
_cf_nocache true
```

And here is the code:

```
$mech->post("https://registrar.ucdavis.edu/courses/search/course_search_results_mod8.cfm", 
    Content => {

        termYear => "2014",
        term => "10",
        ...
        subject => "AAS",
        ...
    },
);
```